# why does the interruption int 21h ignore all strings after writing a string filled durring the execution of the program?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

i am trying to print the sum of two 16Bit values so am calculating the sum then constructing the string that contains it but the problem is after i print said string any writing interruptions `mov ah,09 int 21h` are completely ignored, i am using emu8086, here is the code

```
org 100h

    mov ax,2000
    mov bx,3200
    add ax,bx
    mov si,offset result+5
    mov [si],'$'
    mov bx,10

    Fill:

        dec si
        mov dx,0
        div bx
        add dl,48
        mov [si],dl
        test ax,ax

    jnz Fill

    mov dx,offset result
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset msg
    int 21h

ret

result db 5 dup (?)
msg db " is the sum$"
\n db 0ah,0dh, '$'
```

it just prints `result` and ignors `msg`

Comment: You realize offsets start from zero, right? So `result+5` is overwriting the first byte of `msg` thus when you try to print that it's already an empty string. You want `result+4` since you allocated 5 bytes with offsets 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. PS: you should fill your `result` buffer with spaces or zeroes otherwise if the result is less than 4 digits you will have random stuff printed.

Comment: @Jester that is not my issue the code does print `result` what it does not print is the message that follows

Comment: I just love when people claim "that is not the issue" (especially if they don't even try the provided fix). Trust me, it **is** the issue. Try reading what I wrote again. By putting `$` at `result+5` you are truncating your `msg` to an empty string that is why nothing is printed.

Comment: @Jester i did not quite understand what you were saying at first, but i do now and it indeed was the problem thanks, can you make it an answer so i can make it the answer of this question?

Comment: I don't think this is likely to help anybody else ... just delete the question.

Comment: @aimen__ Please don't edit the question with the correct solution. It invalidates the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> result db 5 dup (?)
> msg    db " is the sum$"
> ```

With these data definitions, memory is set up as follows:

```
result 0    <- offset result+0
       0    <- offset result+1
       0    <- offset result+2
       0    <- offset result+3
       0    <- offset result+4
msg         <- offset result+5   <- offset msg+0
       i                         <- offset msg+1
       s                         <- offset msg+2
                                 <- offset msg+3
       t                         <- offset msg+4
       h                         <- offset msg+5
       e                         <- offset msg+6
                                 <- offset msg+7
       s                         <- offset msg+8
       u                         <- offset msg+9
       m                         <- offset msg+10
       $                         <- offset msg+11
```

When you write the terminating $ for your *result* at `offset result+5`, you **overwrite** that space character by which the *msg* text starts. This in turn means that when you ask DOS to display the *msg* text, DOS immediately stumbles upon the string terminator and so nothing gets displayed.

**The solution is NOT to write the $ character at `offset result+4`**

Instead you need to enlarge the buffer for the result so it can hold **6** bytes.
The value in the `AX` register that you convert could require 5 digits. Therefore you need a buffer of 5+1 bytes.

```
result db 6 dup (?)
```

As a shortcut that avoids having to write the $ character via the code have:

```
result db 5 dup (?), '$'
```

---

> ```
> mov dx,offset result
> mov ah,09h
> int 21h
> ```

Using the offset of *result* could produce garbage on screen!
The good solution here is to use the value in the `SI` register at the end of the conversion. It already points at the first digit of the number. How convenient!

```
    org  100h

    mov  ax, 2000
    mov  bx, 3200
    add  ax, bx
    mov  si, offset result+5
    mov  [si], '$'
    mov  bx, 10

Fill:

    dec  si
    xor  dx, dx
    div  bx
    add  dl, '0'
    mov  [si], dl
    test ax, ax
    jnz  Fill

    mov  dx, si            <- This is offset of first digit.
    mov  ah, 09h
    int  21h

    mov  ah, 09h
    mov  dx, offset msg
    int  21h
    ret

result   db 6 dup (?)
msg      db " is the sum$"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also optimize the program by doing this and eliminating complexity of unnecessary terminating '$'.

```
    org 0x100

    mov ax,2000
    mov bx,3200
    add ax,bx
    mov si,offset result+4
    mov bx,10

Fill:
    mov dx,0
    div bx
    add dl,48
    mov [si],dl
    dec si
    test ax,ax
    jnz Fill

    mov dx,offset result
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    ret

result   db   '      is the sum', 10, 13, '$'
```